# Using this.getSharedPreferences keeps throwing NPE

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to make a simple app that has a few pages using pageViewer, on the main page it has two buttons and two counters. One counter increases passively, the other shows by how much. One button increases the first counter by one per click and the other button increases the passive. Up to there I'm all fine and dandy. But now I'm attempting to save the values using SharedPreferences. However, when I run the code it throws an NPE on the line

`SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("savedInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Here's the full MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("savedInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
StandFragment standFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    standFragment.setTotalMoney(prefs.getInt("totalMoney", 0));
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    prefs.edit().putInt("totalMoney",standFragment.getTotalMoney()).apply();
}
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos){
        switch(pos){
        case 0: 
            standFragment = StandFragment.newInstance("STAND");
            return standFragment;
        case 1: return CartFragment.newInstance("CART");
        case 2: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("THIRD");
        case 3: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("FOURTH");
        case 4: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("FIFTH");
        default: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("Default");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return 5;
    }
}
}
```

And the StandFragment.java:

```
public class StandFragment extends Fragment{

private int totalMoney;
private int moneyPerSec;
private int moneyPerClick;
Handler handleCounter = new Handler();
TextView counter;
TextView perSecCounter;
Button buttonMoney;
Button buttonMoneyPerSec;



public void setTotalMoney(int money){
    this.totalMoney = money;
}
public int getTotalMoney(){
    return totalMoney;
}
public void setMoneyPerSec(int money){
    this.moneyPerSec = money;
}
public int getMoneyPerSec(){
    return moneyPerSec;
}
public void setMoneyPerClick(int money){
    this.moneyPerClick = money;
}
public int getMoneyPerClick(){
    return moneyPerClick;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stand_frag, container, false);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    buttonMoney = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.buttonMoney);
    buttonMoneyPerSec = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.buttonMoneyPerSec);
    counter = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvMoney);
    perSecCounter = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvMonPerSec);

    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvStandFrag);
    tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));

    handleCounter.post(updateCounter);
    if (savedInstanceState==null){
        moneyPerSec = 1;
        moneyPerClick = 1;
        totalMoney=0;
    }
    else{
        moneyPerSec = savedInstanceState.getInt("moneyPerSec");
        moneyPerClick = savedInstanceState.getInt("moneyPerClick");
        totalMoney = savedInstanceState.getInt("totalMoney");
    }

    buttonMoney.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            totalMoney += moneyPerClick;
            counter.setText(""+totalMoney);
            perSecCounter.setText(""+moneyPerSec);
        }
    });
    buttonMoneyPerSec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            if (totalMoney>=10){
                totalMoney-=10;
                counter.setText(""+totalMoney);
                moneyPerSec++;
                perSecCounter.setText(""+moneyPerSec);
            }
        }
    });
    return v;
}

Runnable updateCounter = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        totalMoney += moneyPerSec;
        counter.setText(""+totalMoney);
        handleCounter.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
public void onPause(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    savedInstanceState.putInt("totalMoney",totalMoney);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("moneyPerSec",moneyPerSec);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("moneyPerClick",moneyPerClick);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

}
public static StandFragment newInstance(String text){

    StandFragment f = new StandFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", text);

    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}
}
```

Edited `onCreate()` and `onPause()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("savedInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    standFragment.setTotalMoney(prefs.getInt("totalMoney", 0));
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("savedInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs.edit().putInt("totalMoney",standFragment.getTotalMoney()).apply();
}
```

Comment: Move the `prefs` initialization to inside the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Alright, did that... I would also need to initialize it in the onPause() method as well right? It now throws an NPE for `standFragment.setTotalMoney(prefs.getInt("totalMoney", 0));`

Comment: "I would also need to initialize it in the onPause() method as well right?" - No. "It now throws an NPE for..." - `standFragment` is null.

Comment: But wouldn't it only be in scope inside the onCreate() method? If I remove it from the onPause() method it tells me `prefs cannot be resolved`. And for the NPE, would it be better if I assigned the totalMoney using SharedPreferences when the StandFragment is created? (In the onCreateView() method)

Comment: Move just the initialization, not the declaration.

Comment: You can assign the variable however you want, but at that point in your code, you've not instantiated `standFragment` yet.

Comment: I moved the instantiation, and setting total money from inside the StandFragment class' onCreateView()  method seems to work for me. So I guess problem solved, thanks!